# How to get rid of 'Unversioned Files' in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

Is it possible to hide/get rid of 'Unversioned Files' in a default view of 'Local Changes'?[image]

I found 'Show unversioned files' checkbox in Settings -> Version Control -> Commit but there is no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add files to the .gitignore file you don't want to add them to the git history.

IntelliJ provides a context action for it
[image]